# Is there a discrepancy between the graph in Stackdriver and the configuration threshold?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

Looking at the [Google Cloud API Monitoring metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub), it looks like the oldest_unacked_message_age is in seconds:

[image: oldest_unacked_message_age]

However, when trying to set up a policy and using the graph to the right, the value set in the configuration threshold seems is different from the threshold metric depicted in the graph on the y-axis. The threshold, I think, would be in seconds due to the definition of the metric, but the graph's y-axis units seems to indicate that 300 corresponds to milliseconds.

[image: Discrepancy between the oldest_unacked_message_age (should be in seconds) and the graph metric (ms)]

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a discrepancy between the metric itself (measured in seconds) and setting the threshold (measured in milliseconds). We will look into fixing the issue so that the two use the same units. In the meantime, you would have to set the value to 300,000 to compensate for the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I was using the seconds value, 300, and that actually seems to work.